# json parse error, can't find solution

Tags: php, json, parsing

i don't understand why i have a parse error. Someone could help me?

Client

```
function test() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php?action=setpawn',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.updated);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown + textStatus);
            }
        });
}
```

Server (PHP)

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$response['updated'] = true;
json_encode($response);
```

Comment: You didn't bother to check what response you got using your browser's development console?

Comment: there will be no output since there is no echo

Comment: @kevinabelita - I know there won't be any output. Key is for the OP to realize his mistake by utilizing simple steps. Had he used them, there would be no need to ask this question since he'd arrive to the conclusion on his own. Instead of fixing someone's bugs, it's better to teach them *how* to do it on their own.

Comment: @N.B. then i guess we'll just have to hope the OP realizes it, by the way, my first comment wasn't referring to yours

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the error is not a parse error, but that the result is not output....

Can you try this?

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$response['updated'] = true;
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to send your json. Instead of

```
json_encode($response);
```

you need

```
echo json_encode($response);
```